# License Visual Studio Code (or VsCodium)

Tags: license, open-source, visual-studio-code

When I want to download Visual Studio Code I saw that the version on official website isn't open source, under the download link we can see: "By using VS Code, you agree to its license and privacy statement."

So I think, this version isn't open source. Moreover the github version contains telemetry.

I see their is a project without telemetry and totally open source: VsCodium.
But when I saw the github of this project, I noticed a small numbers of contributors compared to Visual Studio Code.

My question is: 
A small project with lower contributions than a big project can cause problems 1) of security 2) of performance ?

This question applies to the choice between VsCode or VsCodium.

Thanks

Comment: @karel I don't see it anywhere in the package list.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=vscode&searchon=names&suite=eoan&section=all or just `code`, and neither is codium or vscodium.  It's in "Ubuntu Software" but under a "Proprietary" license so it's not really a "native Ubuntu package".  IANAL but, like the OP, I see that the invasive telemetry would fail Ubuntu's package requirements, but I believe that (VS)codium would be ok to package in Universe, and yet the proprietary one is the only one available without sideloading packages. Feels like the wrong way around to me.

Answer (score 1):

> VSCodium is a fork of Microsoft's popular Visual Studio Code editor. It's identical to VS Code with the single biggest difference that unlike VS Code, VSCodium doesn't track your usage data. Microsoft's Visual Studio Code is an excellent editor not only for web developers but also for other programmers. Due to its features, it’s considered one of the best open source code editors.

<sub>**Source:**  [VSCodium: 100% Open Source Version of Microsoft VS Code](https://itsfoss.com/vscodium/)</sub>

In addition to the aforementioned extravagant praise for VS Code, it has the additional advantage of being installable from Ubuntu Software or from the terminal with this command:

```
sudo snap install codium --classic
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in general, Will I chose a small project with small contributors or big project ( performance and security ) ?
I formuled more correctly this question in my topic. Thanks

Comment: The code-insiders snap package is a great application that I use it every day, so of course I would recommend it to everyone, but please don't interpret my extravagant praise for VSCode as deprecation of the security or performance of VSCodium.

Comment: Ok, I understand VsCode is good IDE.
The command in the terminal install the open source version of this project ? (not the binary on the offical website which isn't open source)

Comment: So, I think that isn't the open-source version

Comment: The version on github is under MIT license but the version on the official website and the code-insiders is on a privacy license (Microsoft product license) : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq